# Storing the date selected from a kendoui calendar control in a global variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, kendo-ui

I have a typescript file and using kendoDatePicker. If I select a date and I do alert(this.selectedDate1) I am able to get the date I selected.
However, on the click of a button I call the getInvoices() method below and tried to retrieve the selectedDate1 value. It is always undefined. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
        selectedDate1: Date;
        selectedDate2: Date;

        createDatePicker = function (controlNum: number) {
                    var datePicker = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).kendoDatePicker();
                    datePicker.data("kendoDatePicker").destroy();
                    datePicker.empty();

                    var datePickerControl = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).kendoDatePicker({               
                        change: function (e) {
                            if (controlNum === 1) {
                                this.selectedDate1 = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                                alert(this.selectedDate1);
                            } else {
                                this.selectedDate2 = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                                alert(this.selectedDate2);
                            }                    
                        }               
                    }).data("kendoDatePicker");            
                }


        getInvoices() {
                 alert(this.selectedDate1);
                 // returns undefined all the time.
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the fix, then the explanation...

```
change: (e) => { // <--
    if (controlNum === 1) {
        this.selectedDate1 = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).data("kendoDatePicker").value();
        alert(this.selectedDate1);
    } else {
        this.selectedDate2 = $("#datePicker" + controlNum).data("kendoDatePicker").value();
        alert(this.selectedDate2);
    }                    
}
```

Whenever you work with events, you lose the scope of the `this` variable. The `this` that you were putting `selectedData1` on (and that you were alerting on) was not actually your class.

Using an arrow function introduces an intermediate variable that will make sure you target the class within the event callback.

Comment: Your solution works pretty good. So the (e) => is very important ?

Comment: Yes - it looks pretty minor, but it actually preserves the meaning of `this` inside that function - so it's a fundamental change.